# Where to place yesterday

Tags: usage

Which one of the following two sentences is more correct

> I went yesterday to the bank to collect the passbook.

> Yesterday to collect the passbook I went to the bank.

I think the second one is correct because in the first sentence position of **yesterday** is not correct. As a rule I studied that **adverbs of time like yesterday** come at the end of the sentence.

so the most appropriate sentence would be

> I went to the bank yesterday to collect the passbook

But this sentence was not given in the options I had to choose the corrects answer from.

Comment: But in the example you say is correct, _yesterday_ is not at the end of the sentence! Actually it _is_ correct, but it would also be correct to say, if you were telling someone what you did the day before, "Yesterday I went to the bank to collect the passbook."

Answer (score 2):

It is normal to say “I went to the bank yesterday to collect the passbook” or “I went to the bank to collect the passbook yesterday”. One or both of these sentences should have been given as an option.

The first given sentence is unusual but is correct and emphasises that it was yesterday that you went (rather than some other day).

The second given sentence is understandable but is awkward and unusual; most people would say it is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I know of no rule that says "adverbs of time come at the end of a sentence".  I know of a trend that longer phrases come at the end (end weight)

So avoid "To collect a passbook, I went to the bank" unless you have a good reason for this order.

The position of a short adverb like "yesterday" is more flexible. I'd favour putting it first, in a sentence with neutral tone.

> Yesterday I went to the bank to collect a passbook.

It is also fine  placed after bank (but a comma helps)

> I went to the bank yesterday, to collect a passbook.

I would avoid splitting "went" from "to the bank", as these two are closely related. It might be possible to have

> I went *yesterday* to collect my passbook.

With strong emphasis on "yesterday" but this is no longer neutral in tone.